# PHP Fatal error: Class UpdateHelper\ComposerPlugin contains 2 abstract methods in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I want to install laravel on my windows but getting below error

Using below command install laravel

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 learning-app
```

But getting below error in command prompt after run the composer command

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class UpdateHelper\ComposerPlugin contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Composer\Plugin\PluginInterface::deactivate, Composer\Plugin\PluginInterface::uninstall) in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\kylekatarnls\update-helper\src\UpdateHelper\ComposerPlugin.php on line 11
```

Trying all the commands like composer update but not getting any success.

My php version PHP 7.3.27

Anyone have idea how to solve then let me know

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install the laravel framework locked at a version released more than 2 years ago, is there a reason for this?

Also, what is the version of your composer (run `composer --version`)? If you're at the version 2 try downgrading to v1 and try again with the same command, if you really want the 7.0 version of Laravel (or simply install the newest version of the framework).

Comment: If i tried install laravel version 8 or 9 that time also getting same error. when run composer --version showing same error. Not getting exact solution

Comment: @Praful what did running `composer --version` show?

Comment: Yes i run the command composer --version but in that case also showing same error.

Comment: @Praful Even running the command outside of the project folder (in your home folder, for example)? Well... I assume you tried reinstalling composer and still have the same error too?

Comment: When created project inside the htdocs that time i am getting this error.